# Deep Link from messenger App to my app is not working?

Tags: android, deep-linking, messenger

I’m trying to setup an universal link to my app that my users can share on facebook. I can make it work on email, sms, browser, as follows:

1- If the user don’t have the app, it redirects to a custom URL or the AppStore
2- If the user have the app, it opens the app, including info to open the app in a customized state.
When I try to share the same link on the facebook wall or in facebook messenger, it always opens up the custom URL that I have set, even if I have the app installed.

and it works in apps like whatsapp.

What am I missing?

Comment: Also struggling with this - did you ever figure it out?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet and i am sad because the answers in this topic are very scarce.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: any update on this issue?

Comment: I think you can't do anything on that ... It depens on how facebook (messenger) uses your link ! I landed here because I'm facing the same with a playstore link... Messenger opens it in their crappy web browser and won't let the playStore app open ... Facebook just want to know where you browse won't change in a while IMO